# The properties of traces or metric properties?

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-spaces, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds

If $X,Y \in \mathfrak{X} M$, $M$ is a manifold and $g$ is its metric. if $\hat{\nabla}$   and $\nabla$ are Levi-Civita and statistical connection, respectively. then:
$$K:= \nabla - \hat{\nabla}  $$

Let $e_1, e_2, \dots, e_n $ are  an orthonormal frame around $x_0$. Why do we have this?

$$\sum^n_{i=1} g(K_Y e_i , K_Z e_i ) = g(K_Y , K_Z ) $$

(note that, $K_X, K_Z$ are endomorphisms, and $g(K_X, K_Z)$ is the scalar product of two endomorphisms)

Indeed, these equations are part of this article:
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QBndn.png)

Comment: What kind of objects are $K_Y,K_Z$? What does $g(K_Y,K_Z)$ mean? (These are rhetorical questions.)

Comment: These relationships are part of an article. I attached other equations to my question in the form of a screenshot

Comment: $K_Y, K_Z$ were introduced. @Kajelad